# Load Data Local infile - Most efficient way / quickest?

Tags: php, file-io

I was wondering which would be the most efficient way to use the Load Data Local infile.

I have a number of php scripts that  use this function, each of which puts date from each of my suppliers into my database. The files are located on my ftp server, which is in a seperate domain from where my database is (well at the moment it will be running these scripts from my local machine, but same principle applies).

So, for example one of the scripts reads:

```
$sql = "
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'ftp://user:pass@domain.com/feeds/feed1.csv'
etc.........
";
```

So, my question is, would it be more efficient, and i guess i mean quicker overall, to first download each csv into a local directory and use that as the reference in the above command?

Comment: You want to load sql statements into your server which you retrieve via an insecure network connection? Wow.

Answer (score 0):

For the loading time it makes little difference if you preload the scripts or lod the on-the-fly, provided they are only loaded *once*. Otherwise of course it makes sense to hold local copies.

But what puzzles me here is: That snippet you gave does *not* hold `csv` data. Instead it (most likely) holds `php` code which you most likely include and evaluate. This certainly is effective, but also pretty insecure if you load the files from remote via unsecured connections (read: 'ftp server' and the like). What if someone dropps a script at your server which contains something like `rm -fR /`? I know the web server does not have sufficient rights for this, it is just an example. Use your imagination. At least you should validate what you are loading. And this is certainly *much* easier if you have data instead of code you evaluate.

I suggest you use a local `csv` or better `json` or `yaml` serialized data file, implement a validation routine in something like `php` and feed your sql server with the result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply, however, im a bit confused with your comments about "that snippet does not hold csv data, instead it holds php code" and "its pretty insecure". Could you explain what you mean? and if there is a better "more secure" method what is it, perhaps a link or explanation  would be great. Clearly i am new to coding, and am trying to learn. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I mixed two cases indeed. The files you load via that most likely indeed contain csv data. With insecure I mean what I wrote in the answer: you are loading files via an insecure network connection: you use the 70th ftp protocol which offers no protection at all, transfers everything including passwords and the like in clear text and is very easy to intercept. Are you not afraid to load data which someone else smuggled into your connection? Anything could happen...

Comment: How else would i download/load my csv data into my database without using a user as pass to connect to my ftp directory? Thanks again for your help

Comment: FTP is a protocol from the stone ages. It should not be used any more. Use either the modern replacement `sftp` which offers strong encryption and is more friendly to firewall administrators, or directly its base, the `ssh` protocol. Both protocols allow connections and data exchange by using asymetric keys instead of insecure password based authentication. You should have absolutely no problems to find tons of documentation and examples about this topic. Have a try using google :-)